# Junit: Testing default constructor, dead code warning?

Tags: java, junit

I am attempting to test the default constructor for a class, using Junit:

```
// testing default const
    public void testCaesarCipher() {
        CaesarCipher c1 = new CaesarCipher();
        if (c1 == null) {

            assertTrue(false);

        } else {
            assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error of "Dead code", how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the check for `c1` being null - that's provably impossible. A constructor can *never* return `null`.

You *may* want to test that your constructor doesn't throw an exception - in which case just:

```
public void testCaesarCipher() {
    new CaesarCipher();
}
```

... is fine. The fact that the constructor returns without throwing an exception is *all* that the test will prove though, at execution time. (The presence of the test is a compile-time check that there's a parameterless constructor, of course.)

I expect your other tests will need to call the constructor anyway though, in which case do you really think it's worth having this test at all?

Additionally, if you really *did* want to check that some value wasn't null, you should use:

```
assertNotNull(c1);
```

That's much clearer than your `if`/`else`. And in cases where you want to programmatically fail, just call `fail()` rather than `assertTrue(false);`.

Comment: Thanks, So assertNotNull is enough to be able to ensure that the constructor is working as intended?

Comment: @RNI2013: No, read my answer again, carefully: a constructor can never return null, so using `assertNotNull` would be pointless. It's a check that could never, ever fail *whatever* your constructor did. If you really want to check that your constructor returns without throwing an exception, just call it, as per my first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

At that position, `c1` cannot be `null`. Get rid of the `if` check.

First, a constructor invocation cannot return `null`. Any use of `new ...` will return a non-null reference.

Second, remember that a constructor initializes your object. What you probably want to test is if that initialization happened as you expected it.

Comment: if the if not needed though in order to check the test works?

Comment: @RNI2013 A constructor invocation cannot return `null`. Maybe your unit test should test the initialization of the object.